# GC pauses of 5 seconds but mark, sweep and compact take less than 1 second

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, aix

I have an AIX server running a JVM process with 8 GB heap using gencon GC policy. Today I had 5s pause time which is concerning. I looked at the event in the GC log but couldn't figure out where all that time is spent.

```
<con event="collection" id="1" timestamp="Oct 22 13:34:10 2015" intervalms="0.000">   <time exclusiveaccessms="0.195" />   <nursery freebytes="871692288" totalbytes="966367232" percent="90" />   <tenured freebytes="375809024" totalbytes="7516192768" percent="4" >
    <soa freebytes="0" totalbytes="7140383744" percent="0" />
    <loa freebytes="375809024" totalbytes="375809024" percent="100" />   </tenured>   <stats tracetarget="2430736896">
    <traced total="2804446392" mutators="2591437504" helpers="213008888" percent="115" />
    <cards cleaned="1874" kickoff="102056216" />   </stats>   <con event="remembered set scan">
    <stats objectsfound="17649" traced="110458224" timetakenms="129.797" />   </con>   <con event="final card cleaning">
    <stats cardscleaned="334" traced="9118008" durationms="7.732" />   </con>   <gc type="global" id="1" totalid="929" intervalms="0.000">
    <classloadersunloaded count="162267" timetakenms="4957.805" />
    <refs_cleared soft="1942" threshold="32" weak="164659" phantom="0" />
    <finalization objectsqueued="120" />
    ***<timesms mark="258.390" sweep="33.125" compact="0.000" total="5267.373" />***
    <nursery freebytes="904360200" totalbytes="966367232" percent="93" />
    <tenured freebytes="3848182720" totalbytes="7516192768" percent="51" >
      <soa freebytes="3472373696" totalbytes="7140383744" percent="48" />
      <loa freebytes="375809024" totalbytes="375809024" percent="100" />
    </tenured>   </gc>   <nursery freebytes="904360200" totalbytes="966367232" percent="93" />   <tenured freebytes="3848182720" totalbytes="7516192768" percent="51" >
    <soa freebytes="3472373696" totalbytes="7140383744" percent="48" />
    <loa freebytes="375809024" totalbytes="375809024" percent="100" />   </tenured>   <time totalms="5406.538" /> </con>
```

How can I find which activity part of the full GC is taking the bulk of the pause time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time taken for scan of class loaders is not accounted for in total:

```
<classloadersunloaded count="162267" timetakenms="4957.805" />
```

You have 162267 class loaders in memory taking 4957.805ms to scan. This seems to be known problem, workaround and fix are here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ76742

Comment: Does that mean my application will halt for the whole 4.9s? My assumption is that this means I have 258.390 (mark) + 33.125 (sweep) + 4957 (unload classloaders) = 5267ms where the server will not respond to any requests. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Unloading classloaders  is part of global GC cycle. It is not reported under mark/sweep/compact as those referee to data heap of your application and classloaders are your executable code. This article may prove helpful in understanding where those classloaders come from: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-nativememory-aix/, see section "Classes and classloaders"

Comment: That's a spot on answer to my bounty question and my following question too. You fully deserve your bounty points. Enjoy :) The -Xgc:classUnloadingKickoffThreshold parameter doesn't help me because I'm using IBM Java 5 but the article in your comment pointed me towards a java argument I have which is -Xshareclasses:none. I assume that disabling the sharing of class data means the application will begin to use duplicate classloaders and it's the source of growing ClassloadersLoaded number. Am I correct in thinking I should remove it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any sample GC logs attached but based on your description, you're running the CMS collector. Long pauses are often caused by a full GC which happens sometimes with this collector - it's just mostly concurrent. I would suggest uploading some sample GC logs during the problematic times and also check out this article called '[Understanding CMS GC Logs](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs)'.

Comment: Well, gc is slow by design (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Walks), still it might be a good idea to call it manually (System.gc) every now and then, instead of letting it start at its own will. [This comment belongs to the original question -- my fault, sorry]

Comment: I'm not sure calling System.gc() will have the effect you want because it isn't guaranteed to invoke the garbage collector. It's basically a suggestion to the JVM. Secondly, the JVM optimizes when it calls the garbage collector throughout your program's lifetime, constantly trying to find a minimally intrusive sweet spot. It's really hard to be better than the JVM at that. Thirdly, the CMS collector is pretty fast. The graph reference you have only refers to stop-the-world pauses that the GC does, and CMS tries to minimize that using several concurrent phases before it gets to that point.

Comment: Uploading other GC logs would just show you a lot of scavenge GCs. The one GC event where I'm seeing the 5s pause is shown in my original question. Other GC events have no relation to it. Please let me know if I'm wrong in saying this. It would help me to know that surrounding GC events (before or after) have any impact on the full GC duration.

Comment: Well, calling System.gc might do nothing, but also might release memory (I have experiences when that happened) so there is no risk in call it.
And, if it were so clever, this topic wouldn't exist;)

Comment: Zsigmond, fair counterargument to my point about the JVM being clever. :-) I've had memory come down before when calling it as well, but you really can't bank on it. My experiences have been more consistently positive when tuning the collector via JVM args.